# Formatted shell script output

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, printf

How can I fix the output width using `printf`?

This is an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OK=$(printf '\t%+50s\n' OK)
FAIL=$(printf '\t%+50s\n' FAIL)
for i in a aa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; do
        echo "$i $OK"
done
```

Output:

```
a                                                       OK
aa                                                      OK
aaa                                                     OK
aaaa                                                    OK
aaaaaa                                                  OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                                                  OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                                               OK
```

I want something like:

```
a                                                       OK
aa                                                      OK
aaa                                                     OK
aaaa                                                    OK
aaaaaa                                                  OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                                       OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                              OK
```

Answer (score 20):

An easy way:

pipe your script to `column -t`

```
$ script.sh | column -t
a                           OK
aa                          OK
aaa                         OK
aaaa                        OK
aaaaaa                      OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa           OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  OK
```

Answer (score 19):

Use the following `printf` approach to get the needed output:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in a aa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa; do
    printf '%-50sOK\n' $i 
done
```

Script output:

```
a                                                 OK
aa                                                OK
aaa                                               OK
aaaa                                              OK
aaaaaa                                            OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                                 OK
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa                        OK
```

---

- `OK` - as static string is moved to the *FORMAT* (`printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]`)
- `$i` - considered as `printf` argument

Answer (score 6):

You didn't use a tool that formats output and, as `$i` gets wider, your output fails to align.

Replace

```
echo "$i $OK"
```

with

```
printf "%-50s %s\n" "$i" "$OK"
```

(replace "foo" by actual string).

where

- `50s` is a fixed width 50 char string,
- `-` (minus) left-justify the string.
- see `man 3 printf` for details about the format string.